# VS Code - Can Not Write in User Settings

Tags: json, macos, visual-studio-code, settings

Im trying to check the option in settings "Format on Save" in VS Code (and I have Prettier installed) but every time it gives me an error message saying "Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again." and when I open it up I see the following.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your settings.json contains an error.

Removing ["terminal.intgrated.automationShell.osx":] should fix the issue.